# How to set a checkpoint in the process of the start of the nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx, hook

I want to set a checkpoint(like doing hash operation on specified files) in the process the start of the nginx.

Is there anyone know how to deal with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LSM HOOK function "task_create()" to hook all the process and filter the process by "current->comm"